# how to assign hotkeys?

Tags: python, tkinter

please help to assign hotkeys to the top entry menu "OPEN".

```
import tkinter

def fileOpen():
    print('qwerty')

def makeMenu(parent):
    top = tkinter.Menu(parent) 
    parent.config(menu = top)                           

    file = tkinter.Menu(top, tearoff = False)
    file.add_command(label = 'Open...', command = fileOpen, accelerator = 'ctrl+o')
    top.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file)

    #top.bind_class(top, '<Control-Key-o>', fileOpen)

root = tkinter.Tk()

makeMenu(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I need to by pressing "CTRL + O" runs the function "fileOpen"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Bind `fileOpen` to the root window (`root`) instead of the menubar (`top`).
2. Make `fileOpen` accept an argument, which will be sent to it when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

Below is a version of your script that addresses these issues:

```
import tkinter

######################
def fileOpen(event):
######################
    print('qwerty')

def makeMenu(parent):
    top = tkinter.Menu(parent) 
    parent.config(menu = top)                           

    file = tkinter.Menu(top, tearoff = False)
    file.add_command(label = 'Open...', command = fileOpen, accelerator = 'ctrl+o')
    top.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file)


root = tkinter.Tk()

############################################
root.bind_all('<Control-Key-o>', fileOpen)
############################################

makeMenu(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The stuff I changed is in comment boxes.

Comment: you might want `bind_all` rather than `bind_class`. The former makes the binding work for all windows, the latter makes it only work only when the root window has focus. It's a moot point if you only ever have a single window, but it's important to know the difference.